# "Cannot find table 0"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a button, with an event onClick(), when I press down the button it Should add in two different tables (Seuil and Notifier). This is My code

Button Code :

```
//Here I instanciate my Connexion class Where I fill the data table and the data set

con.seConnecter();

//Here I verify if the table Seuil has already a similar record 

if (con.verifierExistance("Seuil", "idSerieMateriel", DropDownList1.selectedItem) &&
    con.verifierExistance("Seuil", "idMagasin", DropDownList2.selectedItem))
{

// If exist, do an update

    con.charger("update Seuil set qteMin ='" + txtQteMin.Text + "', qteMax ='" + txtQteMax.Text + "' where idMagasin='"+DropDownList1.selectedItem+"' and idSerieMateriel ='" + DropDownList2.selectedItem + "'", true);
}
else
{
    //if not Insert a new one
    con.charger("insert into Seuil values('DropDownList1.selectedItem', 'DropDownList2.selectedItem', '" + txtQteMin.Text + "', '" + txtQteMax.Text + "')", true);
}

//and in the end, it should add a row in the table 'notifier'
con.charger("insert into Notifier(matricule, qteMin, qteMax, typeMateriel, Serie, idMagasin, date) values('10', '" + txtQteMin.Text + "', '" + txtQteMax.Text + "', '" + cmbType.SelectedItem + "', '" + cmbSerie.SelectedItem + "', '1', '" + DateTime.Today + "')", true);
```

My class connexion

```
public void charger(string query, bool variable)
{
    commande = new SqlCommand(query, connexion);
    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commande);
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    if (variable)
    {
        dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

The function that verifies the existance of a similar code

```
public Boolean verifierExistance(string tableName, string primaryKey, string textBoxValue)
{
    charger("select * from " + tableName+ " where " + primaryKey+ " ='" + textBoxValue+ "'", true);
    if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the error

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.

Ligne 61 :         if (variable)
Ligne 62 :         {

Ligne 63 :             dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
Ligne 64 :         }
Ligne 65 :     }
```

Comment: Step through your code using the debugger and view the dataSet object. You are probably not populating it correctly.

Comment: Is the data in your database? If so then the first half of the query seems irrelevant. If not then you should focus on that part first.

Comment: YEs there is data in my table

Comment: What makes me go crazy is that when I check my database I find that the row was updated in the table 'Seuil' but no rows added to the table 'Notifier'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cant get a dataset when you update or insert a row in db, you will get it only when you select data,

In this case your

> dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

in

> charger

function will be empty

hence it throws a error when you try to access the **1st table at 0th index**

Comment: if you want to see if data has been inserted or updated use commande.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @sabrina if(dataset.Tables.Count>0) { do something with table } else { nothing there, continue }

Comment: @MatthewMartin I did what you told me and I got this new error "The object reference is not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Then check to see if dataset (which isn't necessarily the name of your DataSet) is null. If the DataSet isn't null, then the Tables property will exist and if there are no tables, then the Count property will still exist. Then you can decide what that means based on the details of your app. (Like maybe this was an insert statement and returns nothing as expected, maybe this is an insert statement and it normally returns a select @primar_key, but if it didn't then you know you have an error condition, depends on teh specific scenario)

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I just don't know why I didn't pay attention to it, the probleme was a small 'true' that had to be changed with a 'false' in my query

```
con.charger("insert into Seuil values('DropDownList1.selectedItem', 'DropDownList2.selectedItem', '" + txtQteMin.Text + "', '" + txtQteMax.Text + "')", FALSE);
```

Thank you very much for your time, help and effort ^_^ <3